# `gnome-control-center` Will Not Open

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, plugins, gtk

Here are the logs:

```
(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GStreamer-WARNING **: 13:55:35.536: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopengl.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopengl.so: undefined symbol: gst_gl_caps_replace_all_caps_features

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GStreamer-WARNING **: 13:55:35.536: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopengl.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopengl.so: undefined symbol: gst_gl_caps_replace_all_caps_features

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 13:55:35.621: cannot register existing type 'GstDataURISrc'

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.621: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 13:55:35.621: cannot register existing type 'GstDataURISrc'

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.621: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.621: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.621: gst_element_register: assertion 'g_type_is_a (type, GST_TYPE_ELEMENT)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.621: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.621: gst_element_register: assertion 'g_type_is_a (type, GST_TYPE_ELEMENT)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 13:55:35.623: cannot register existing type 'GstAggregator'

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 13:55:35.623: cannot register existing type 'GstAggregator'

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: gst_element_register: assertion 'g_type_is_a (type, GST_TYPE_ELEMENT)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:6872): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:55:35.623: gst_element_register: assertion 'g_type_is_a (type, GST_TYPE_ELEMENT)' failed
```

This is the log from calling it from the command line, and if I try to do it graphically (e.g. by clicking "Settings") then it simply never opens.

Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit:** This happens also with Brasero, giving the same errors. This looks like a problem with glib but using `apt reinstall` for glib doesn't work. I would try purging it with `apt remove` or `dpkg --force-all` but I don't want to break my system.

Is there a way to fix this.

Comment: same problem here!, Any solution?